# chnaging a specific column in a specific row with for loop

Tags: python, awk, sed, grep, cat

I have a file with following content

```bash
### beginning of executable commands

### load the necessary module files

module load GCC/11.3.0 OpenMPI/4.1.4 CP2K/9.1

### your program goes here (a.out is an example)
$MPIEXEC $FLAGS_MPI_BATCH cp2k.popt -i nvt_10.inp -o nvt_10.out
```

I want to change "nvt_10.inp" in iterative way such that the number changes only. Like nvt_20.inp, nvt_30.inp ......

Please help me to get a solution of it.

I tried with awk but not able to get it.

Comment: please update the question with the `awk` code you've tried, the (wrong) result generated by your code, and the (correct) expected result

Answer (score 0):

Use the `seq` command to generate a sequence of numbers. This example will generate numbers from 10 to 100, increase 10 each time:

```bash
for number in $(seq 10 10 100)
do
    echo $MPIEXEC $FLAGS_MPI_BATCH cp2k.popt -i nvt_${number}.inp -o nvt_${number}.out
done
```

Run it, if you are satisfied with the outcome, you can remove the `echo` to make it executing for real.

Comment: Please copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about.